# The Python version issue when I deploy the page on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

When I deploy the page on heroku:

```
wumengtiandeMacBook-Pro:web wumengtian$ git push heroku master
```

and then:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing Python-3.6.2
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python-3.6.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !    Push rejected to safe-peak-44258.
```

so I search https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
It shows the following image:

[image]
Is the problem really dependent on the version? Or something else? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try delete runtime.txt and deploy again.
I got same problem and it worked for me just before.